# How do WorkAway and HelpXers do volunteer work for individuals when UK requires Visa and charity sponsorship

Tags: united-kingdom

I would like to volunteer as WorkAway or HelpXer in UK and Ireland, but it seems that UK law only lets you volunteer for a registered charity.  Most of the hosts on these sites are not registered charities.

Comment: Related (visitor): http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/64051/does-a-volunteer-through-helpx-or-workaway-need-a-visa

Comment: Do you have a link or reference for this item in UK law?